# How to create routing table with flood method in omnetpp

Tags: nodes, dijkstra, omnet++, neighbours

The goal is to create a routing table, so each node can send from wherever it is, a message to the node with the most neighbors.

Let's say i have this network

[image]
So every node's mission is to send a message to node4. To accomplish, there has to be a routing table to give guidance on routing process for all nodes.

I want to know how to send a message containing information about the senders and the receivers id and gate. So I can combine the information from all nodes with a multihop process into one routeTable which every node is aware of. Also it is vital for perfomance issues, to not send a message to a node twice.

After all nodes knows the routeTable they have to start sending messages to node4. This will stop when a certain time (t), passes.

I know that i can find the size of neighbor for each node with gateSize(). But other than that I don't know how to send a message containing all this information that I want. I know the algorithm Dijkstra, but I don't know how to implement it into omnet. Can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

The information you are looking for are implemented in the `cMessage` class.

```
int senderModuleId;        // sender module ID -- set internally
int senderGateId;          // source gate ID -- set internally
int targetModuleId;        // destination module ID -- set internally
int targetGateId;          // destination gate ID -- set internally
```

You can find the **Class Reference** [here](https://doc.omnetpp.org/omnetpp/api/classomnetpp_1_1cMessage.html).

Comment: This is the way I send a message
`int n = gateSize("gate$o");
int k = intuniform(0, n-1);
send(msg,"gate$o", k);`
If the k is supposed to be the gateId then the getArrivalGateId() has to be equal. Instead of that i get a big integer like 1572865..
How to use this integers to create the routeTable and also send messages?